# Как скрывать иконку удаления сообщения от НЕ-владельца этого сообщения?

Tags: javascript

У меня есть приложение-чат. Задача - показывать кнопку "удалить" только владельцу самого сообщения.

Изначально пытался решить эту задачу как-то вроде

```
const checkMessageOwner = !messages ? [ ] : messages.some(user => user.owner === curUser.id);
const cardDeleteButtonClassName = `message__btn ${
checkMessageOwner ? "message__btn_display_true" : "message__btn_display_false"}`;

Где messages - это массив с сообщениями. 
Где owner - id владельца сообщения
Где curUser.id - это айдишник текущего пользователя.
```

И с единичным сообщением вроде как работает. То есть у другого пользователя иконка удаления не появляется. Но если нажать на кнопку удаления своего сообщения, то иконки "удалить" появляются снова на всех сообщениях, включая не свои. Куда можно смотреть? Буду благодарен за помощь.

Также иконки удаления появляются даже в случае добавления нового сообщения.

```
Запрос к АПИ на удаление: 
export function handleDeleteMessage(token, id) {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      await chat.deleteMessage(token, id);
      dispatch({ type: REMOVE_MESSAGE, payload: id });
    } catch (err) {
      if (err === 409) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    } finally {
    }
  };
}
Сам редьюсер: 
export const chatReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_MESSAGES:
      return { ...state, messages: action.payload };

    case REMOVE_MESSAGE:
      const id = action.payload;
      return {
        ...state,
        messages: [...state.messages.filter((item) => item._id !== id)],
      };

    case ADD_MESSAGE:
      return {...state, message: action.payload};

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

[image: Изображение]

Comment: Больше похоже что проблема у вас в коде удаления сообщения. А его вы не показали.

Comment: function remove() {
    deleteMessage(isToken, id);
  } 

Там ничего особенного. Просто запрос к АПИ и все.

Comment: А перерисовываете потом чат как?

Comment: Никак не перерисовываю. По-моему проблему состоит в том, что если .some находит хотя бы одно сообщение овнера, то он дает абсолютно всем карточкам иконку удаления, а не конкретно одному

Comment: Вы используете метод some. То есть получается если в массиве есть хоть одно сообщение где user => user.owner === curUser.id, то оно возвращает true.

Comment: Значит, это не подойдет для решения данной проблемы?

Answer (score 0):

Получилось решить проблему очень просто. Я просто прописал JSX-код, где сравнил, является ли идентичным айдишник пользователя и овнера.

[image: Решение]